# Ban member from other guild if banned in main guild

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I want it where, if a user gets banned from this specified guild, it will ban them in every other guild that the bot is in. Do I use fetch bans to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we continue you need to make sure that you are requesting the following intents when creating your bot, as they are necessary to achieve your goal: `GUILDS`, `GUILD_BANS`.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS]
});
```

You should also set up a constant called `MAIN_GUILD_ID` or something along those lines:

```js
const MAIN_GUILD_ID = 'ID';
```

Now you need to listen to the [`guildBanAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildBanAdd) event and check if the [`GuildBan.guild#id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildBan?scrollTo=guild) equals the main [`Guild#id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=id) (making sure the user was banned in the main [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild)).

```js
client.on('guildBanAdd', async ban => {
    if (ban.guild.id !== MAIN_GUILD_ID) return;
});
```

Then you can loop through all of the [`Guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) your bot is in and ban the user there.

```js
client.on('guildBanAdd', async ban => {
    if (ban.guild.id !== MAIN_GUILD_ID) return;

    // Getting the guilds from the cache and filtering the main guild out.
    const guilds = await client.guilds.cache.filter(guild => guild.id !== MAIN_GUILD_ID);

    guilds.forEach(guild => {
        guild.members.ban(ban.user, {
            reason: `${ban.user.tag} was banned from ${guild.name}.`
        }).then(() => {
            console.log(`Banned ${ban.user.tag} from ${guild.name}.`);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(`Failed to ban ${ban.user.tag} from ${guild.name}.`, err);
        });
    })
});
```

*I'm assuming this is for a private bot that is in a few guilds, otherwise, if the bot is in a few hundred or more guilds it will get your application rate-limited pretty fast.*